# how to calculate quality of http request served

Tags: linux, apache, shell, httprequest

I have a shell script that calculate the tps, average response time and quality of response time in percent. But I think quality response formula is not correct, please suggest how to calculate the quality of response time in terms of  percentile of 95% percent.

```
calculation () {
echo "starting calculation of the data in the files:" 
if [ -f "/tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log" ]
then
    total_request=$( cat /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | wc -l )
    total_500E_request=$( cat /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | awk -F"\"" '{ print $3}' | awk -F" " '{ print $1}' | grep "^5[0-9][0-9]$" | wc -l)
    average_response_time=$( cat /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | awk -F"\"" '{ print $9}' | awk '{sum+=$1; ++n} END { rounded = sprintf("%.2f", sum/n ); print rounded }')
    percentile=$( cut /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log -d '"' -f9 |sort -n| awk 'BEGIN{c=0} {total[c]=$1; c++;} END{ rounded = sprintf("%.2f", total[int((NR*0.95)-1)] ); print rounded } ' )
    head_time=$( head /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | awk -F" " '{ print $4 }' | awk -F"[" '{ print $2 }' | awk -F"/" '{ print $1"-"$2"-"$3}' | awk -F":" '{ print $1" "$2":"$3":"$4}' | head -1 )
    tail_time=$( tail /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | awk -F" " '{ print $4 }' | awk -F"[" '{ print $2 }' | awk -F"/" '{ print $1"-"$2"-"$3}' | awk -F":" '{ print $1" "$2":"$3":"$4}' | tail -1 )
    sec_old=$(date -d "$head_time" +%s)
    sec_new=$(date -d "$tail_time" +%s)
    DIFF=$(( (sec_new - sec_old) ))
    tps=$(echo "scale=2; $total_request/$DIFF * 1" | bc )
    request_servered_in_defined_sec=$( echo "scale=2; $total_request/$DIFF * $second" | bc )
    sum=$(cat /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | awk -F"\"" '{ print $9}' | awk '{sum+=$1; ++n} END { print sum }')
    quality_per_sec=$( echo "scale=5; $sum/$total_request * $second" | bc )
    quality_score=$( echo "scale=5; $quality_per_sec/$sum * 100" | bc )
    if [ $total_500E_request -gt $threshold   ]
    then
            echo "Count of 500 error request increases so sending mail to the team:" 
            send_mail error
    else
            echo "Writing all the stats in a file and wait for the next run:" 
            send_mail all
            exit
    fi

fi
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way got the correct way below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the is a legacy code i was using , Just to be standard i have used fluentd first to send the logs to logmatic and in logmatic it was very easy to calculate the percentile and everything.

https://app.logmatic.io/
http://www.fluentd.org/

Answer (score 0):

correct function

calculation () {

echo "starting calculation of the data in the files:"

if [ -f "/tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log" ]
then
        total_request=$( cat /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log |wc -l )
        total_500E_request=$( cat tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | awk -F"\"" '{ print $3}' | awk -F" " '{ print $1}' | grep "^5[0-9][0-9]$" | wc -l) 
        percentage_500E=$( printf "%.2f" $(echo "scale=5; $total_500E_request/$total_request * 100" | bc) )
        average_response_time=$( cat /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | awk -F"\"" '{ print $9}' | awk '{sum+=$1; ++n} END { rounded = sprintf("%.2f", sum/n ); print rounded }')
        percentile=$( cut /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log -d '"' -f9 |sort -n| awk 'BEGIN{c=0} {total[c]=$1; c++;} END{ rounded = sprintf("%.2f", total[int((NR*0.95)-1)] ); print rounded } ' )
        head_time=$( head /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | awk -F" " '{ print $4 }' | awk -F"[" '{ print $2 }' | awk -F"/" '{ print $1"-"$2"-"$3}' | awk -F":" '{ print $1" "$2":"$3":"$4}' | head -1 )
        tail_time=$( tail /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | awk -F" " '{ print $4 }' | awk -F"[" '{ print $2 }' | awk -F"/" '{ print $1"-"$2"-"$3}' | awk -F":" '{ print $1" "$2":"$3":"$4}' | tail -1 )
        sec_old=$(date -d "$head_time" +%s)
        sec_new=$(date -d "$tail_time" +%s)
        DIFF=$(( (sec_new - sec_old) ))
        tps=$(echo "scale=2; $total_request/$DIFF * 1" | bc )
        request_servered_in_defined_sec=$( echo "scale=2; $total_request/$DIFF * $second" | bc )
        quality_per_sec=$( awk -F"\"" -v val=$second '$NF < val' /tmp/log/tps_access/access$today_date.log | wc -l )
        quality_score=$( echo "scale=1; ($quality_per_sec * 100)/$total_request" | bc  )
        value=$( echo $percentage_500E'>'$threshold | bc -l )
        if [ $value -eq 1   ]
        then
                echo "PERCENTAGE of 500 error request increases so sending mail to the team:" 
                send_mail error
        else
                echo "Writing all the stats in a file and wait for the next run:" 
                send_mail all
                exit
        fi

fi
}